# Enable autoreply with certain date for Outlook

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, mapi

This VBA code is in Excel. The version is Office 365.

The error raised is

> Type mismatch

in SetProperty xxxxx0X661E001F and also 0x661F0040.

I tried to change the strMessge to variant or change to UNICODE.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub SetAutoReply()

    Dim objOutlook As Outlook.Application
    Dim objNamespace As Outlook.Namespace
    Dim objStore As Outlook.Store
    Dim objPropertyAccessor As Outlook.propertyAccessor
    Dim strStartDate As String, strEndDate As String
    Dim dtStartDate As Date, dtEndDate As Date
    Dim strMessage As String

    ' Set the auto-reply start and end dates and times
    dtStartDate = "05/16/2023 08:00:00" ' Set the start date and time (MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS)
    dtEndDate = "05/16/2023 17:00:00" ' Set the end date and time (MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS)
    strMessage = "I am currently out of the office and will return on [end_date]."

    ' Initialize Outlook
    On Error Resume Next
    Set objOutlook = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0

    ' Get the default mailbox
    Set objNamespace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set objStore = objNamespace.DefaultStore
    Set objPropertyAccessor = objStore.PropertyAccessor

    ' Set the auto-reply settings
    With objPropertyAccessor
        strStartDate = Format(dtStartDate, "yyyy-mm-dd\THH:MM:ss")
        strEndDate = Format(dtEndDate, "yyyy-mm-dd\THH:MM:ss")
        .SetProperty "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x661D000B", True 'Enable auto-reply
        .SetProperty "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x661E001F", strMessage 'Set auto-reply message
        .SetProperty "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x661F0040", strStartDate 'Set auto-reply start date
        .SetProperty "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x66230040", strEndDate 'Set auto-reply end date
    End With

    ' Release the objects
    Set objPropertyAccessor = Nothing
    Set objStore = Nothing
    Set objNamespace = Nothing
    Set objOutlook = Nothing

    MsgBox "Auto-reply has been set from " & dtStartDate & " to " & dtEndDate & ".", vbInformation, "Auto-reply Set"

End Sub
```

Comment: If you run this code in Outlook VBA, does it fail the same way?

Comment: My requirement is our code can activate the automatic reply in Excel

Comment: First confirm it is valid Outlook VBA. If it fails Excel is a red herring in this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last two properties (`0x661F0040` and `0x66230040`) are of `PT_SYSTIME` type (`0x0040`), therefore you must pass a DateTime value, not a string. It is your responsibility to convert your data to the right type. In this particular case, use `CDate` function:

```vb
.SetProperty "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x661F0040", CDate(strStartDate) 'Set auto-reply start date
.SetProperty "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x66230040", CDate(strEndDate) 'Set auto-reply end date
```

If you are setting OOF state and range, keep in mind that it cannot be set using MAPI, you need to use EWS for that.

Comment: I have tried to convert the String to Date via CDate function, but it still fail.
And now the another statement also raised error like Set "XXX/0x661E001F" with String.
I don't know which type shall I convert.

Comment: I only know what the `0x661D000B` property is - `PR_OOF_STATE`. I do not know what the other properties are. Can you see them on the store in OutlookSpy (https://www.dimastr.com/outspy - click IMsgStore button)? If you can, try to double click to edit the property and see if an error is returned after you set the property.

Comment: If you are setting OOF range, keep in mind that it cannot be modifier using MAPI, you need to use EWS for that.

Comment: Also, the reply message is not stored on the store object, it is stored as a hidden message.

Comment: I have tried with another approach like below, but somehow all my stores equal 0.
  Set olSession = olApp.Session
    Set olStore = olSession.DefaultStore
    
    ' Check if automatic replies are supported by the default store
    If olStore.ExchangeStoreType = 3 Then
        Set olOofSettings = olStore.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x661D000B")
        
        ' Activate automatic replies within the specified date range
        olOofSettings.StartTime = startDate
        olOofSettings.EndTime = endDate
end if

Comment: 0 is what you should; expect: `OlExchangeStoreType.olPrimaryExchangeMailbox`. Once again, if you need to set the range and reply text, use EWS.

Comment: Hi Dmitry,
Could you give me an example how to call the EWS, after instanlled the OutlookSpy, I can get the current Item ID, playload, etc.
But how I can set the value to the XML and activate the OofSetting?

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-2010/hh532556(v=exchg.80)

Comment: there is only C# code example, whether it means only support programming with C#. I also was not found any link providing VBA code work with EWS.
Could you share me the example or other links? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: I also got that EWS will not support later, it recommend we should use microsoft.graph instead.
Therefore, I think we can try this with Graph.

Comment: You can use XMLHTTP object in VBA to perform HTTP requests, but it is definitely not fun, especially since you need to know teh creadentials in case of Basic aautth, or, even worse, have an token in case of OAuth.

Answer (score 0):

Outlook may apply its own *business rules* on setting low-level properties using the [PropertyAccessor.SetProperty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.propertyaccessor.setproperty) method. Conditions where setting properties fails include:

- The property is read-only, as some Outlook and MAPI properties are read-only.
- The property referenced by the specified namespace is not found.
- The property is specified in an invalid format and cannot be parsed.
- The property does not exist and cannot be created.
- The property exists but is passed a value of an incorrect type.
- Cannot open the property because the client is offline.
- The property is created using the `UserProperties.Add` method. When setting the property for the first time, you must use the `UserProperty.Value` property instead of the `SetProperties` or `SetProperty` method of the `PropertyAccessor` object.

So, as you can see there are too many reasons why the code may fail. I'd suggest playing with any low-level property explorer tool such as `MFCMAPI` or `OutlookSpy` and try to set these properties manually to make sure the values you are trying to assign are valid. If they are valid I'd suggest playing with VBA to make sure the `SetProperty` can be used for that.

Comment: Could you give an example to show the method of  UserProperty.Value or user UserPropertes.add  ?
I find some links, but it still dont work, the error is method does not support.

 Set objStore = objNamespace.DefaultStore
    'Set objPropertyAccessor = objStore.PropertyAccessor
    Dim myUserPro As Outlook.UserProperty
    Set myUserPro = objStore.PropertyAccessor.Add(myPro, olText)

Comment: See https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/08/19/how-to-add-a-custom-property-to-the-userproperties-collection-of-an-e-mail-item-in-outlook/